# Joomla Admin module in "New Article" form?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

In Joomla 1.5, I am interested in developing a fairly simple module that I was hoping would live on the right side of the create new article page. I've created a handful of modules before, one on the admin page at the dashboard that is on the right side that you click to expand/collapse.

So, can I create a module that I could attach to any new article form on the right side, somewhere under "advanced settings" or something?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can do that, but you need to modify some core files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have to be done with a plugin, but com_content was not written to be extended. You would definitely have to modify the core files in order to attach plugins or hard code your changes for it to work.

An alternative would be to switch to using K2 that can be extended through the use of admin plugins.